# G efficiency in Optimal designs

Tags: regression, variance, experiment-design

I am studying Optimal Designs and found a very interesting [article](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10691898.2004.11910631#.XLa7behKhPY) by Peter Goos. In the article he provides an example in the form of an Excel document of generation of Optimal Designs for various models.

I would like to add the calculation for Gefficiency, which I found is defined as:
$$
\text{Geff} = (100 * p) / (n * d) $$
where
$p=$ number of terms in the model
$n=$ number of runs in the design
$d=$ maximum relative prediction variance v over the candidate set, where prediction variance  $v = x(X'X)^{-1}x'$
$x =$ a row in the candidate set
$X =$ the selected design

For a quadratic model:  $y = b_1 + b_2 x + b_3 x^{2} + e$

I have a design matrix **x**

```
run 1   0.15
run 2   0.24
run 3   0.33
run 4   0.42
run 5   0.51
run 6   0.60
```

which leads to an extended design matrix **F**

```
     dy/dB1 dy/dB2  dy/dB3
run 1   1   0.15    0.02
run 2   1   0.24    0.06
run 3   1   0.33    0.11
run 4   1   0.42    0.18
run 5   1   0.51    0.26
run 6   1   0.60    0.36
```

with transpose **F'**

```
1       1       1       1       1       1
0.15    0.24    0.33    0.42    0.51    0.6
0.0225  0.0576  0.1089  0.1764  0.2601  0.36
```

Computing **F'F**

```
6   2.25    0.9855
2.25    0.9855  0.47588
0.9855  0.4759  0.24405
```

and finally  $(F'F)^{-1}$

```
6.7474  -38.47  47.766
-38.47  236.7   -306.19
47.766  -306.19 408.257
```

So the relative prediction variance should be given by $v= x(F'F)^{-1} x' $  However the row $x$ is a scalar and $(F'F)^{-1}$ is a square matrix. How can I calculate the relative prediction variance for each candidate solution?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I am still trying to solve this problem.